# LWC is not working with non-admin profiles

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, web-components

I have created a web component to pre-populate child record fields from parent record,
its working fine when i tested as a **admin**, but its not working when I logged in as **other profiles**,

I'm not using any apex class to get the fields, I have imported fields from parent using schema(ex:**import case_Description from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Description**';) and populating child fields using **defaultfieldvalues** attribute.

any ideas?

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working" if you can.

Answer (score 0):

The LWC fetches data or metadata using LDS i.e, Lightning Data Service.
It always works in user context which means if you have read access on a field you will be able to read data on it. If your user has edit access on a field then you will be able to edit values on it.
Can you please check and make sure your user have Create, Edit rights on objects and Read/Edit access on individual fields